# Stub / Mock all methods of an object in Node.js

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mongoose, mocking, sinon

Writing test cases when working with `Mongoose`, I'd like to `stub` all methods of a model such as `find`, `where`, `toJSON`, etc. and return a simple object as a result. (As that's what a unit test is concerned with, the output of an external service, in this case mongo).

Is there a way to do this using `Sinon` or any other testing framework? Otherwise I would need to write mocks case by case based on the function I'm testing and it becomes more work/code considering that mongoose model methods could be chained and I would need to write mocks for each chain scenario, like:

```
sinon.stub(userStub, 'findOne').resolves(
        {toJSON: sinon.stub().returns(data)}
);
```